# Measure the uniformity of distribution of points in a 2D square

Tags: statistics, distribution, uniform

I am currently running into this problem: I have a 2D square, and have a set of points inside it, say, 1000 points. I need a way to see if the distribution of points inside the square are spread out (or more or less uniformly distributed) or they tend to gather together in some spot area inside the square.

Need a mathematical/statistical (not programming) way to determine this. I googled, found something like goodness of fit, Kolmogorov... and just wonder if there are other approaches to achieve this. Need this for class paper.

So: Inputs: a 2D square, and 1000 points.
      Output: yes/no (yes = evenly spread out, no = gathering together in some spots).

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi! Stackoverflow is really for programming Q&A, you might have better chances on [the math stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Vote to close as it has been asked on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40928/measure-the-uniformity-of-distribution-of-points-in-a-2d-square).

Answer (score 2):

If your points are independent you can just check the distribution for each dimension individually. The [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test (a measure of the distance between 2 distributions) is a good test for this. First let's generate and plot some Gaussian-distributed points so you can see how you can use the KS test (statistic) to detect a nonuniform distribution.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from matplotlib.pyplot import plt
>>> X = np.random.gauss(1000, 2)  # 1000 2-D points, normally distributed
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()
>>> X = scaler.fit_transform(X)  # fit to default uniform dist range 0-1
>>> X
array([[ 0.46169481,  0.7444449 ],
       [ 0.49408692,  0.5809512 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.60877526,  0.59758908]])
>>> plt.scatter(*list(X))
```

[image: 2D Gaussian Scatter Plot]

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
>>> stats.kstest(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X[:,0]), 'uniform')
KstestResult(statistic=0.24738043186386116, pvalue=0.0)
```

The low p-value and high KS-statistic (distance from the uniform distribution) says nearly certainly did not come from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1

```
>>> stats.kstest(StandardScaler().fit_transform(X[:,0]), 'norm')
KstestResult(statistic=0.028970945967462303, pvalue=0.36613946547024456)
```

But they probably did come from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1 because of the high p-value and low KS distance.

Then you'd just repeat the KS-Tests for the second dimension (Y)

Comment: I stumbled across this, and wanted to comment, for anyone else who might be looking for a test like this, that testing multiple hypotheses individually is a bad idea. See https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mgoldman/Section0402.pdf. Ideally you should use a KS-test which tests all dimensions at the same time, as you're dealing with a *joint* probability distribution.

Comment: @komodovaran Indeed. My simplistic approach is only accurate if you are certain that your dimensions are completely independent, as mentioned in the caveat at the beginning. The degree to which your variables (dimensions) are dependent (joint) will determine the degree to which this analysis is inaccurate as a statistical measure. So for approximately independent variables it's an approximate statistical measure. Your approach is more accurate.